# How do append an instance of a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking to create a (very!) basic inventory management system

This is the brief:

> Product Inventory Project - Create an application which manages an
> inventory of products.  Create a product class which has a price, id,
> and quantity on hand.  Then create an inventory class which keeps
> track of various products and can sum up the inventory value.

Here is my code so far:

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, id_num, price, quantity):
        self.price = price
        self.id_num = id_num
        self.quantity = quantity

class Inventory:
    def __init__(self):
        self.product_list = []
        
    def add_item(self):
        id_num = int(input('Enter id: '))
        price = int(input('Enter price: '))
        quantity = int(input('Enter quantity: '))
        self.product_list.append(Product(id_num, price, quantity))
```

I don't understand how to make an instance of the product class append to the product list in testing. I feel like I am way off. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This code appears to do exactly what you want - except that you haven't shown any example of creating an `Inventory` object and then calling `.add_item()` on it.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: Do you fully understand the code you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

The code is fine. You just need to execute :)

Look at this sample I just modified inputs and made static values for fast execution:

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, id_num, price, quantity):
        self.price = price
        self.id_num = id_num
        self.quantity = quantity

class Inventory:
    def __init__(self):
        self.product_list = []
        
    def add_item(self):
        id_num = 1 #int(input('Enter id: '))
        price = 100 #int(input('Enter price: '))
        quantity = 4 #int(input('Enter quantity: '))
        self.product_list.append(Product(id_num, price, quantity))


inv = Inventory()
inv.add_item()
print(inv.product_list[0].price)
```

You should get the print result of 100 which is the price of the item

Comment: Ahhhhhhh! I realised when testing I was doing test_inv = Inventory, instead of test_Inv = Inventory(). Thanks for your help :)